# error: Void method 'undo:' should not return a value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

I get this error (Void method 'undo:' should not return a value ) in this line of code:

```
return image;
```

What's wrong and does somebody know a solution of this error?

**Code:**

```
- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                  @"test.png" ];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
[self->_imagView setImage:image];
return image;
}
```

**EDIT:**

What do I have to say if the "undo" button is tapped the image should be return?

Code:

```
- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender
```

{

}

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                  @"test.png" ];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
return image;
}

- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
{
   if (image != nil)
   {
      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"test.png" ];
      NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
      [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
   }
}
```

Comment: if it's should not return a value, then don't return a value.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return a value from a method with a `void` return type. `IBAction` is really just `void`.

You need to do something else with `image` besides trying to return it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to return anything? To whom?

Just do the steps you have to do to undo. Probably this should be done using an [undo manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoaapp/undomanager.html).

Doing undo yourself is not easy and for sure more work than simply reloading the original (guess: unprocessed) image.

Comment: I have an image which is saved and on the image you can apply filters and now I'll create an undo button which is loading the original image.

Comment: Undoing means to undo the last operation on a stack of operations. To do undo operations outside the system's undo stack is hard to overview and I think, it will break.